# How can I power a NeoPixel ring and strip through Arduino MKR1000?

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, capacitors

I currently have a MKR1000 which is connected to 1 ring with 8 neopixels, 1 strip with 20 neopixels, 1 microwave sensor, 1 speaker, 1 rotary encoder. I am running the NeoPixel positive and negatives through a 220 µF capacitor, and the data pins through 220 Ω resistor.

I am soldering these components onto a board, but currently, when I plug the MKR1000 into my USB it says it's drawing too much power, the Arduino also smokes and I can smell burning, so disconnected straight away.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A schematic diagram would help the understanding your setup

Answer (score 1):

The on-board regulator of an Arduino can supply a maximum of 500 mA when connected to USB, and up to 1000 mA when connected to an external power supply (see [Maximum current from Arduino 5V power pins](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2018/08/16/maximum-current-from-arduino-5v-power-pins/)).

If your components are drawing more current than that, then you will need to use an additional separate power supply for the NeoPixel ring - ensuring that the ground lines of the Arduino's supply and the NeoPixel's supply  are connected.

If the Arduino has been smoking then it may already be damaged. Did you see which part was smoking? If it was a capacitor as shown in [Is my Arduino dead?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/is-my-arduino-dead), then [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/is-my-arduino-dead/54010#54010) may help.